# public class extends JPanel

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, jpanel, extends

I am getting a error that looks like this,

run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ao.Game.main(Game.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - 
   ao.Panel is not abstract and does not override abstract method     
   keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener
    at ao.Panel.<clinit>(Panel.java:15)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

I can't figure out what the problem with the public class is.

There are 2 separate files below.
[Game.java](https://docs.google.com/a/mtlstudents.net/document/d/1pyrQEtcUW5-QZOKFpaKYdL54gvXDey4Yjv9Kx-uCFwk/edit)
[Panel.java](https://docs.google.com/a/mtlstudents.net/document/d/1Vlpdvg3lXHEC3Kw2nJdH9V3HIlIvyq_cIcNCs_RhoUU/edit)

First File:

```
package ao;

import ao.Panel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("2D Shooter Pre-Alpha");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new Panel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Next File:

```
package ao;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author andyoppenheimer
 */
public class Panel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    // panel dimensions
    public static final int WIDTH = 320;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 240;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;
    // main loop
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    private int fps = 60;
    private long targetTime = 1000 / fps;
    // drawing
    private Graphics2D g;
    private BufferedImage image;

    public Panel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        if (thread == null) {
            running = true;
            addKeyListener(this);
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void init() {

        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

    }

    public void update() {
    }

    public void draw() {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public void drawToScreen() {
        Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, null);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    public void run() {

        init();

        long start;
        long elapsed;
        long wait;

        while (running == true) {
            start = System.nanoTime();

            update();
            draw();
            drawToScreen();

            elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
            wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;

            if (wait < 0) {
                wait = 5;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
    }

    public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
    }

    public void KeyTyped(KeyEvent k) {
    }
}
```

Comment: `g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();`  Aaaaaargh!  Whatever resource you are using to learn Java, lose it.  It is rubbish.  Instead go to [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)..  For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.  Also, try actually **reading** the group.  These types of things come up 2-3 times a day!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Could you comment on a better approach and why that line of code disgusts you so much?

Comment: @AndrewThompson you can make your comment as an answer :)

Comment: @nachokk  Unfortunately it does not even begin to address the compilation problem.  I think that has been handled pretty well already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java methods starts with lower case `keyTyped` `keyReleased` and `keyPressed` so you are not overriding `KeyListener` methods.

You can annotate a method with @Override
this  causes a compile error if it doesn't actually override. [Section 9.6.1.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html) says:

> The annotation type Override supports early detection of such problems. If a method declaration is annotated with the annotation @Override, but the method does not in fact override any method declared in a superclass, a compile-time error will occur.

Your class definition will lead to possible **potential** bugs cause

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener
```

Calling `Panel` it's confusing cause already exists java.awt.Panel so call it different. Implementing multiple interface like that brokes [Single Responsability Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) . A possible solution is to make inner classes or anonymous classes. For sure if you don't override a method is not necessary to extends `JPanel`. Take care that if you use `KeyListener` components must be in focus and be focusable and bind it to all keys, instead you can use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Don't use `requestFocus` instead use `requestFocusInWindow()` if you read api it says it's discouraged.

Comment: Thank You, I am feeling really dumb today, had to write this on a plane.  :)

Comment: @RC. why is not an answer?

Comment: it is thew answer, I was just saying that I feel stupid for making this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The class implements the [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) interface but does not provide an implementation for the `keyReleased`, `keyPressed` and `keyTyped` methods specified on the interface.  Instead it provides implementations for: `KeyReleased`, `KeyPressed` and `KeyTyped` which are not properly cased.